# How to include a variable when creating a new table through vba in MS-ACCESS

Tags: database, vba, variables, ms-access

In my latest system design i came into a problem with the following idea:

I wanted to create a new table from the click of a button in a form, but i want the table to get it's name from the `nrof` variable that must get its value from a text field in the form, what i am trying right now, based on actual microsoft documentation is the following:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

Dim num As Integer
Dim nrof As Integer
Dim dbs As Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb
num = Nr_Motores.Value
nrof = PF.Value


    ' Create a table with three fields and a primary
    ' key.
    dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE NewTable " _
        & "(FirstName CHAR, LastName CHAR, " _
        & "SSN INTEGER CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint " _
        & "PRIMARY KEY);"
End Sub
```

The `CREATE TABLE` part is copy/pasted from the documentation, no changes were made yet, I don't know how to include that variable in the name of the table

Comment: Please research concatenating variables with strings using VBA. There are plenty of information either here or google. Also worth checking out **parameterized queries** to protect your database from *sql injections*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the string concatenating the variable with `&`.

Enclose the name in `[]` to allow it to contain characters that would otherwise fail to parse.

```
dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE [" & nrof & "] _
    & "(FirstName CHAR, LastName CHAR, " _
    & "SSN INTEGER CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint " _
    & "PRIMARY KEY);"
```

Comment: thank you, i will try this and post the results in a bit, i had tried with the "[]" but i didnt know i had to use the "&". One more thing, im assuming i can mix fixed text with the variable, like so: Table Nr-[" & nrof & "]
Right?

Comment: If `Nr-` is part of the name it needs to be inside the braces so; `Table [Nr-" & nrof & "] `

Comment: actually in this example, Table would also be part of the name, but i got your point, thank you ;)